# How do I get CSS webkit-scrollbar to work with HTML object tags?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a custom scroll bar using CSS `-webkit-scrollbar`. I have the following code

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        object {
            overflow: scroll;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: green solid;
        }

        object::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 20px;
        }

        object::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        object::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #f50000;
            border-radius: 20px;
            border: 6px solid transparent;
            background-clip: content-box;
        }

        object::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background-color: #1100ff;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="_details">
        <object type="text/html" data="_details.html"></object>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**_details.html**

```
<h1>content</h1>
<br>
<h1>content</h1>
<br>
<h1>content</h1>
<br>
<h1>content</h1>
```

When I open index.html, it's still showing the standard scroll bar.

[image]

Is there a way to get the object tag show the customer scrollbar?
Thanks!

Comment: Fyi, when I add `-webkit-scrollbar` style to a div, it's showing the updated scroll bar. Just can't seem to get it to work on a `<object>` tag.

Comment: `object` is a replaced element. This could be the issue.

Comment: Right, it is. But I figured you should still be able to style the content you're replacing. I'll keep googling and will post here if I find an answer. If not, I'll try to replace the object tag with some JS magic...

Comment: The other "fun" part is you are working with something that is non-standard and somewhat experimental so the result can be "flexible"

Answer (score 0):

To show a custom scrollbar, I found this on Google, [Custom Scrollbar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)
Refer this one.

Comment: I already know how to add a custom scrollbar, my question is how to make it work with <object> tag.